# Background Color based on difference with cell

Tags: vba, excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a VBA code which allows me to allocate background colors to a cell based on its difference with the neigbouring cell to the left.

Allow me to explain:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsEbj.jpg

When you look at the image above you can see:

- `C3` is red because it's value is higher than `B3`.
- `C4` has no color as it's value is equal to `B4`
- `C5` is green because it's value is lower than `B5`

I tried to put this into a VBA code but don't succeed:

```
Sheets("x").Range("C3").FormulaR1C1 =
"=IF(RC>RC[-1],Interior.ColorIndex = 3,IF(RC<RC[-1,Interior.ColorIndex= 4))"
```

another attempt was by recording an IF function:

```
If Sheets("x").Range("C3") > Sheets("x").Range("D3") Then
Sheets("x").Range("C3").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

I'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction as I'm (clearly) no VBA guru.

Comment: Why not use Conditional Formatting?

Comment: The second option you have written should work, if you finish it with "End if" and C3 and D3 are the cells you need. What is the problem with it?

Comment: I'm with Scott. Anyhow your "IF" function attempt should work: what issues do you have with it

Comment: I would first look at conditional formatting, as @ScottCraner suggested. This doesn't require VBA, can be changed around, and you can still use "undo".  If that doesn't work, then I'd turn to VB.

Comment: @ScottCraner Conditional is no option imo... I will insert several collumns and the formatting should always be used on the first two rows.

Comment: @Vityata I have tried several times and several different sheets/tabs/cells but nothing seems to happen with the second function :S.
The first function just results in the C3 cell turning into text "FALSE"

Answer (score 0):

```
If Sheets("x").Range("C3") > Sheets("x").Range("D3") Then
Sheets("x").Range("C3").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

This piece of code works. there were some range issues which originaly resulted in a failure of this code.

Thank for your support!