# Use Function on range

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Following my previous question:
[Background Color based on difference with cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429924/background-color-based-on-difference-with-cell)
. I would now like to apply this function to a range of rows.

The function I'd like to apply is:

```
If Sheets("X").Range("E18") > Sheets("blocked(R)").Range("D18") Then
    Sheets("X").Range("E18").Interior.ColorIndex = 10
```

The range I need to apply this function to is fixed: `D18:E1200`.
However, there will be an active filter on this range.

The `Autofill` code of course is not working and writing a line of code for each of 1200 rows would be crazy.

I have been searching and reading and I think it must be something like:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:C2")

For Each row In rng.Rows
  For Each cell in row.Cells
    'Do Something
  Next cell
Next row
```

But I don't seem to get it to work, I was hoping for some pointing into the right direction of the community.

Comment: [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) with a native worksheet formula is a better solution.

Comment: @Jeeped as rows and columns will be inserted. A conditional is no option. I need to be able to run the formatting code on this specific range after each addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub test()

    Dim rngApply As Range
    Set rngApply = Sheets("X").Range("D18:E1200")
    Dim varIndex As Variant

    For Each varIndex In rngApply
        If varIndex.Value > Sheets("blocked(R)").Range("D18") Then
            varIndex.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```